# How can I make no line space using regex?

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, richtextbox

I have below sentences on my richtexBox1 have can I make only one line space between each line  and dont make any line space if sentence start with Create table and ends with semicolomn

***result:***

```
ALTER TABLE "COURSE" DROP CONSTRAINT "CRSE_CRSE_FK";




ALTER TABLE "ENROLLMENT" DROP CONSTRAINT "ENR_STU_FK";

ALTER TABLE "ENROLLMENT" DROP CONSTRAINT "ENR_SECT_FK"; 

ALTER TABLE "ENROLLMENT" ADD CONSTRAINT "ENR_STU_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("STUDENT_ID") REFERENCES "STUDENT"("STUDENT_ID") ENABLE;

ALTER TABLE "ENROLLMENT" ADD CONSTRAINT "ENR_SECT_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("SECTION_ID") REFERENCES "SECTION"("SECTION_ID") ENABLE;


CREATE TABLE "COMP1" 
(   "EMPID" NUMBER, 
"EMPLNAME" VARCHAR2(20), 
"EMPFNAME" VARCHAR2(20), 
"DEPTNO" NUMBER, 
"MGRID" NUMBER, 
PRIMARY KEY ("EMPID") ENABLE
);

CREATE TABLE "COMP12" 
(   "EMPID" NUMBER, 
"EMPLNAME" VARCHAR2(20), 
"EMPFNAME" VARCHAR2(20), 
"DEPTNO" NUMBER, 
"MGRID" NUMBER, 
PRIMARY KEY ("EMPID") ENABLE
);
```

***Expected result***

```
    ALTER TABLE "COURSE" DROP CONSTRAINT "CRSE_CRSE_FK";  

    ALTER TABLE "ENROLLMENT" DROP CONSTRAINT "ENR_STU_FK";

    ALTER TABLE "ENROLLMENT" DROP CONSTRAINT "ENR_SECT_FK"; 

    ALTER TABLE "ENROLLMENT" ADD CONSTRAINT "ENR_STU_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("STUDENT_ID") REFERENCES "STUDENT"("STUDENT_ID") ENABLE;

    ALTER TABLE "ENROLLMENT" ADD CONSTRAINT "ENR_SECT_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("SECTION_ID") REFERENCES "SECTION"("SECTION_ID") ENABLE;        

    CREATE TABLE "COMP1" 
    (   "EMPID" NUMBER, 
    "EMPLNAME" VARCHAR2(20), 
    "EMPFNAME" VARCHAR2(20), 
    "DEPTNO" NUMBER, 
    "MGRID" NUMBER, 
    PRIMARY KEY ("EMPID") ENABLE
    );

    CREATE TABLE "COMP12" 
    (   "EMPID" NUMBER, 
    "EMPLNAME" VARCHAR2(20), 
    "EMPFNAME" VARCHAR2(20), 
    "DEPTNO" NUMBER, 
    "MGRID" NUMBER, 
    PRIMARY KEY ("EMPID") ENABLE
    );
```

***My Code (only adds 2 lines empty)***

```
           List<string> rt = new List<string>();
            foreach (string line in richtexBox1 .Lines)
            {
                if (line != "")
                {
                    rt.Add(line);
                    rt.Add("");
                }
            }
            richtexBox1 .Lines = rt.ToArray();
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: `rt.Add("");` - you add an empty line for every "real" line and wonder, why there are extra empty lines?! o_O - In your `foreach` try this: `rt.Add(line); if (line.Trim().EndsWith(";")) { rt.Add(""); }`. Because as you said, you only want an empty line if the previous one "ends with semicolon".

Comment: I don't understand your code? You taking each line from a rtb (`foreach (string line in richTextBox1 .Lines)`) then adding them into a list (`rt.Add(line)`) with empty lines (`rt.Add("")`) then putting them back into the rtb (`richTextBox1 .Lines = rt.ToArray()`)? is this intended?

Comment: There are some white spaces that want to remove and make 2 line spaces every after each semicolomn!!!

Comment: I dont understand your question. What do you want to do?

Comment: To remove spaces from a line: [String.Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/t97s7bs3.aspx). To remove an empty line: `if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) { continue; }` see [string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx). To add a new line if the previous ends with a semicolon: showed that already.

Comment: @NicolasTyler , my richTextBox1 has some empty lines before Create Table .... sentence and want to remove all empty lines before create Table and make only 2 lines every after each semicolomn

Comment: I updated my entire question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try this with this

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> rt = new List<string>();
        foreach (string line in richTextBox1.Lines)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line.Trim()))
            {
                rt.Add(line);
            }
            if (line.Trim().EndsWith(";"))
            {
                rt.Add("\n");
            }
        }
        richTextBox1.Lines = rt.ToArray();
        richTextBox1.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: this seems to add 2 new lines between each ";"

Comment: only improvement is to replace the List<string> with an array to prevent having to convert it to an array after.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for clearing up your question:

```
while (richTextBox1.Text.Contains("\n\n"))
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace("\n\n", "\n");
string[] linesafter = richTextBox1.Lines;
for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Length; i++)
    if (richTextBox1.Lines[i].EndsWith(";"))
        linesafter[i] = linesafter[i] + "\n";
richTextBox1.Lines = linesafter;
```